# run nmb cable in conduit

Tags: subpanel

I've decided to run a new 60 amp sub panel in my garage using 6/3 NMB. Can I run it 35' through 1" pvc conduit from main panel to sub panel without stripping off the outer sheathing?

Comment: Have you ever heard of running individual wires in conduit?

Comment: You can. But you should get separate wires. Harper or one of the other pros will explain in excruciating detail with code references etc. But basically there are wires designed for use in conduit which are much easier to fish through than NM cable. Plus you can't simply strip NM cable to use the individual wires in conduit because it is not rated for that use. Plus individual wires should be a little cheaper anyway - and most people (except electricians) don't have a bunch of 6/3 lying around extra.

Comment: On such a short pull .why only 60 amps ? Pennies more could run 100 amps. To a garage.

Answer (score 3):

### Stripping the sheath is *prohibited*

The wires you use have to be identified, i.e. have markings on them.  Interior wire in NM cable is not marked.

You have to pig-wrestle the entire NM cable through, sheath and all.  Good luck.

### The correct wires are THWN or XHHW

If you want the flexibility of individual wires, you want THWN or XHHW type. You need a #10Cu green or bare ground and three #6Cu wires, one neutral white or gray, and two hots any other color.  They can be the same color.

If you don't like the price of #6Cu try #4Al.

If you run #3Cu instead, you can run 100A on that wire.  You will need to bump the ground wire to #8Cu and it will need to be bare. This will be a harder pull, though.

Comment: okay if I move up to 100A what size THWNN wires and how big is the conduit?

Comment: @Will #3Cu for conductors, #8Cu bare for ground, will just  fit in your 1” pipe.   If you haven't laid the pipe yet, price a larger size like 1-1/2 and cheaper #1Al conductors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, and may not have to be in pipe the whole way. Pulling cable may be tough ,to do. You could have gotten single stranded wire for easy pulling.  Make sure you lube pull and a good pull line. And no you do not strip,the wire. Only has to be in pipe ,subject to damage areas only.